# One connectionstring for SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, web-config, connection-string, simplemembership

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app and I'm defining connection strings in my `web.config`. I'm using [SimpleMembership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) which by default wants to use a connection string with the name `DefaultConnection`

I'm also using `EntityFramework 5` to access the same database and store my app data. My `EntityFramework` context is called `AppContext`. Therefore, my context wants to by default use a connection string with the name `AppContext`.

My current solution is to define two connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="REMOVED" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="AppContext" connectionString="REMOVED" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What's the commonly used solution here? I assume this is a common scenario and people are either overriding the default name of the EntityFramework connection string or the SimpleMembership connection string.

Comment: I can not find anything particularly worrying in this code.

Comment: This could help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575311/using-simplemembership-with-ef-model-first

Comment: Yep, I think that answers my question, if you want to post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Hum, my turn to have a question: who is the boss ? :-)

You don't have to accept the default settings, unless they really matches what **YOU WANT** to do.

I don't see why you would need to have 2 exactly identical connection  string to the same database! I am sure it can work that way, but it's not a big deal to make either one use the other connection string. For example, by default in AccountModels, I have:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<webpages_Membership> Membership { get; set; }
}
```

I just need to change "DefaultConnection" to "AppContext" in there to have SimpleMembership using the same connection string than Entity Framework:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("AppContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<webpages_Membership> Membership { get; set; }
}
```